# Excel VBA Delete Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a program that will delete or create rows based on what a user puts in a certain row. For example, if the user puts in 3, but there are only 2 rows, then it will insert 1 row. If there were 5 rows, it would delete rows 4 and 5. It seems like it should be an easy code, but I am having the hardest time having it actually delete/create the rows that I want it to. My code is as follows:

```
Sheets("Summary").Select

x = Cells(29, 3).Value
i = 7

Sheets("Weighted I").Select

Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = "TOTAL"
    i = i + 1
Loop

i = i - 7
If i > x Then   
    dlt = i - x + 7

    For cnt = 7 To dlt
        Rows(cnt).EntireRow.Delete
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next    
ElseIf i < x Then
    crt = x - i + 7

    For cnt = 7 To dlt
        Rows(cnt).EntireRow.Insert
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem when deleting rows. Imagine you are moving through your for loop one row at a time and deleting:

```
For cnt = 7 To dlt
    Rows(cnt).EntireRow.Delete
    cnt = cnt + 1
Next
```

You are on row 7 and you delete it. This shifts all of your rows up. Row 8 is now Row 7. You then increase your `cnt` variable by 1 (to 8) and delete row 8. But you missed row 7, which was row 8... it's crazy bananas.

Instead, change your for loop to work backwards:

```
For cnt = dlt to 7 step -1
    Rows(cnt).EntireRow.Delete
    cnt = cnt - 1
Next
```

This way the row shifting doesn't affect your `cnt`.

Comment: JNevill, that worked perfectly. Thank you, I knew it just had something to do with my logic in the code. Thank you so much for the help!