# For each loop doesn't seem to iterate over every row

Tags: excel, vba

I want the code to check every row whether it is 0 or not. If it is equal 0, the row should be deleted. The code works, but it seems that it doesn't go in every row. I put in debug.print to show how many rows are before running and after. If I run the code multiple times it gets to the point it should heading (106 rows should be not deleted)

```
Dim dblZeilen As Double
dblZeilen = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count
Debug.Print dblZeilen

For i = 2 To dblZeilen + 1
    If Worksheets("Data").Range("N" & i).Value = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Data").Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i 

dblZeilen = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count - 1
Debug.Print dblZeilen
```

The results from debug.print in order:

- 460
- 279
- 279
- 187
- 187
- 142
- 142
- 121
- 121
- 112
- 112
- 109
- 109
- 107
- 107
- 106

So after the 8th iteration running the code, the result was right.
I've also tried another way to get this running, which didn't help.

```
Dim dblZeilen As Double
dblZeilen = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count
Debug.Print dblZeilen
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngBereich As Range

Set rngBereich = Worksheets("Data").Range("N2:N" & dblZeilen)

Worksheets("Data").Range("N2:N" & dblZeilen).NumberFormat = "0.00"

For Each rng In rngBereich
    If rng = 0 Then
        rng.Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next rng

dblZeilen = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count
Debug.Print dblZeilen
```

Comment: Always delete running from last line and going up.

Comment: Or gather qualifying ranges with union and delete all in one go at end. This is a frequently asked question so there will be lots of examples. You should also remove the .Select and ActiveCell lines and simply work with the rng range object.

Comment: There are tons of questions about that, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042717/excel-vba-delete-rows. Bottom line is what Vincent G wrote: When deleting do it backwards. This is not limited to Excel, this is true for any indexed list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
For i = 2 To dblZeilen + 1
```

with:

```
For i = dblZeilen + 1 To 2 Step -1
```

When deleting, run the loop backwards to avoid corrupting the index.

*(there may be other problems)*

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student and Vincent G. This worked flawless and makes absolutely sense!