# Run for loop one time not several times to delete rows

Tags: excel, vba

Last time I wrote about the loop occasionally deleting my output. So I changed it. The problem I have is with the below part is that it deletes the first occasion of a row having a certain background color and being empty. To delete all rows, I need to run the same loop several times while the expected behavior is to find all rows that are empty in column 'B' and have a background color of 24 and delete them. What could cause it?

Many thanks,
Eka

```
Sub test()
Dim LR as long, i as Long
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, "B")) And Cells(i, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 24 Then
Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
Else
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042717/excel-vba-delete-rows run the loop backward so you can achieve expected result. fololw the link.

Comment: Thank you, @techie, I changed it to the below and it worked just fine `Sub test()
Dim i As Long
For i = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row To 2 Step -1
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, "B")) And Cells(i, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 24 Then
Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
Else
End If
Next
End Sub